# How to compile ReactJS for use on server with command line arguments?

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, reactjs

I've decided to try out ReactJS. Along with that, I've decided to use Gulp for compiling .jsx to .js, also for the first time.

I can compile it no problem for the client use with browserify. Here's my gulp task:

```
browserify("./scripts/main.jsx")
.transform(
    babelify.configure({
        presets: ["react"]
    }))
.bundle()
.pipe(source('bundle.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./scripts/'));
```

But since I use PHP to generate data, I need to get those data to node. If I use browserify, it will prevent me from using process.argv in node. I can save data to file and read that file in node, so I wouldn't need to pass the whole state to node, but I still need to pass the identifying arguments, so the node knows which file to load.

What should I use instead of browserify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

I have learnt that you can create standalone bundles with browserify, so I've compiled all the server code I need (components + rendering) as a standalone bundle. Then I have created small node script which is responsible only for reading arguments, loading data and sending it to the rendering code.

I'm not sure if this is a proper way how it should be done but it works.

Here's code for the "setup" script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Server = require('./server.js');

if (process.argv[2]) {
    region = process.argv[2].toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/, '');

    if (region != '') {
        var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../tmp/' + region + '.json', 'utf8'));

        console.log(Server.render(data.deal, data.region));
    }
}
```

This way I only need to deploy two files and I still can easily compile jsx to js.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compile a React module to es5 for use on the server, use Babel itself.

A module that may help with reading and writing files is this one: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Have you considered posting and getting from a database?

Comment: I did consider db, but since there are more things that I need to do (e.g. guess user's region), and I already do it in PHP, I don't want to have that logic in two places (and I don't want to switch to Node entirely either).

With Babel, can I write the rule so it would bundle all files together like browserify does?